# How do I get stronger in Pirates Ahoy?

Tags: pirates-ahoy

In Playfish's Facebook game, Pirates Ahoy, how do I get stronger and increase my chances of victory over the monsters in the ocean?  Will upgrading my ship help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official FAQ](http://forum.playfish.com/showthread.php?t=190758513.):

**13 - Do ship parts help with battles against monsters?**

They do not. The outcome of the battles are randomly decided.